# How to scp into a remote server with only root user and no password

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, passwords, scp

I have a development HW with linux running and only root user. Upong bootup it asks me only username (which is root) and no password. So I assume there is no password for root user. Now I want to transfer a file from host system (Ubuntu 16.04) to this HW using scp but I keep getting asked for a password.

`$ scp my_local_file root@192.168.292.123: /home/root`

`root@192.168.292.123's password:`

`Permission denied`

When I leave it blank and press enter, it says permission denied. I even tried the password as root and still no luck. I am pretty sure it worked before but dont remember giving it any password. How to scp to this remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time ssh is set up not to allow empty password login and never to allow root to login with a password at al.  You can check your configuration on the device or log onto it and scp from it to the host system.  (Check sshd_config for PermitRootLogin and PermitEmptyPasswords settings.)

Your best bet is probably to put a keyfile on the device and have an easier and more secure future. :)